# Upload an image to imgur with php

Tags: php, api, curl, imgur

I am using php to upload images to imgur this is the code i am using:

```
    $id = 'clientId';
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array( 'Authorization: Client-ID ' . $id));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array( 'image' => base64_encode($image)));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    $response = json_decode($response);
    curl_close ($ch);
```

The code is working but i want the images to be upload to my account album if anyone know how to do it, Also i am trying to understand why do i have to set `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` for the code to work, I did visit the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) but if anyone can give me some background about how and why i will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: Have you had a look at their [API Documentation](http://api.imgur.com/endpoints/album)? This appears to be well documented.

Comment: I will take a look, But can you explain please about CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send these parameters with your request:

```
image   required    A binary file, base64 data, or a URL for an image
album   optional    The id of the album you want to add the image to. For anonymous albums, {album} should be the deletehash that is returned at creation.
type    optional    The type of the file that's being sent; file, base64 or URL
name    optional    The name of the file, this is automatically detected if uploading a file with a POST and multipart / form-data
title   optional    The title of the image.
description optional    The description of the image.
```

So, how about this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' => base64_encode($image), 'album' => 1234));
```

Comment: Hey, I did try 'album' => my album code, But i get an error that says: That i am not the owner of that album, Do you know why....

Comment: Are you logged in when you post the images? https://api.imgur.com/oauth2#authorization

Comment: Not i am not logged in i only supply the client id, Can you some me an example please...

Comment: This is what i was trying https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=my client code&response_type=token

Comment: You need an authorization token from imgur, see what's been done here:
https://gist.github.com/eirikb/7404666

Comment: https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/addclient First make an account and add an application, then you'll get a Client-ID. You then get a token from here https://api.imgur.com/oauth2/authorize?response_type=token&client_id=1e9d0bad8e66dcb and do a POST with the token and your image and album id to here https://api.imgur.com/3/image

Comment: Hey thank you i know now how to refresh the token and use the token to inset images into my album, Can you just tell me what is the difference between this url: https://api.imgur.com/3/image.json to this url: https://api.imgur.com/3/image Doe's the .json is for inserting anonymous images without any related album and /image will take the folder index i guess witch accept 'album' => 'albumId', Am i right?...

Answer (score 1):

By setting CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER to false, it will not verify the domain on the ssl certificate. Usually a certificate is set to xyz.com domain and not all of the xyz's subdomains (more expensive since those certs are less common).

Since it works when you set it to false, it means that their ssl certificate is not created for the specific domain path.

By setting to true, it will try to validate the certificate and will stop the connection if the certificate does not exist for that specific domain path. Hope that's helpful.